# Spring-Batch: how do I return a custom Job exit STATUS from a StepListener to decide next step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

The issue is this: I have a Spring Batch job with multiple step. Based on step one i have to decide the next steps. Can i set status in **STEP1- passTasklet** based on a job parameter so that i can set the Exit status to a custom status and define it in the job definition file to go to which next step.

```
Example
<job id="conditionalStepLogicJob">
<step id="step1">
<tasklet ref="passTasklet"/>
<next on="BABY" to="step2a"/>
<stop on="KID" to="step2b"/>
<next on="*" to="step3"/>
</step>
<step id="step2b">
<tasklet ref="kidTasklet"/>
</step>
<step id="step2a">
<tasklet ref="babyTasklet"/>
</step>
<step id="step3">
<tasklet ref="babykidTasklet"/>
</step>
</job>
```

i ideally want my own EXIT STATUS to be used between steps. Can i do that? will it not break any OOTB flow? is it valid to do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are several ways to do this.

You can use a `StepExecutionListener` and override the `afterStep` method:

```
@AfterStep
public ExitStatus afterStep(){
    //Test condition
    return new ExistStatus("CUSTOM EXIT STATUS");
}
```

Or use a `JobExecutionDecider` to choose the next step based on a result.

```
public class CustomDecider implements JobExecutionDecider  {

    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if (/* your conditon */) {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus("OK");
        }
        return new FlowExecutionStatus("OTHER CODE HERE");
    }

}
```

Xml config:

```
    <decision id="decider" decider="decider">
        <next on="OK" to="step1" />
        <next on="OHTER CODE HERE" to="step2" />
    </decision>

<bean id="decider" class="com.xxx.CustomDecider"/>
```

Comment: You can also use <end on="OTHER CODE HERE" /> if you have no more steps.

Comment: It should also work if you put a "*" in the decision-tag as an else-statement. Does anyone no, it will be interpreted as else? If the decider could return 3 different values, and in the batch-job you only interpret two ways