# Spring Batch flow job transitions

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a following dummy Spring Batch job:

```
return jobBuilderFactory
        .get(REPORT_JOB_NAME)
            .flow(createRequestStep())
                .on("*").to(retriveInfoStep())
                    .on("*").to(notifyAdminStep())
            .end().build();
```

Right now all my transition conditions are `"*"`. Is it possible to return from `Tasklet.execute` method custom statuses in order to declare a many alternative ways to go from one certain step ?

For example something like this:

```
return jobBuilderFactory
        .get(REPORT_JOB_NAME)
            .flow(createRequestStep())
                .goto(
                    .on("STATUS1").to(retriveInfoStep1())
                    .on("STATUS2").to(retriveInfoStep2())
                    .on("STATUS3").to(retriveInfoStep3())
                )
            .end().build();
```

So, based on different statuses(`STATUS1`, `STATUS2`, `STATUS3`) we can go from `createRequestStep` to steps: `retriveInfoStep1`, `retriveInfoStep2`, `retriveInfoStep3`

Comment: Can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411731/spring-batch-how-do-i-return-a-custom-job-exit-status-from-a-steplistener-to-de?rq=1 help?

Comment: Thanks, that's  exactly what I need